# Replace my not elegant code by a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to replace all whitespaces and commas to `|`.
For example:

`809163294,12345678 12345678, 12345678`

should became as:

`809163294|12345678|12345678|12345678`.

I am struggling with regex but getting `809163294||12345678|12345678|12345678`.

Can create a script that will do what I want but it looks not elegant how can be using regex.

```
'809163294,12345678 12345678, 12345678'.replace(/\W/g, ' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean).join('|')
```

How can I change my code to create more elegant and more readable solution?

Comment: IMO you don't need regex for that

Comment: .replace(/\s|\,/g, '|')

Comment: do you have only numbers to separate?

Comment: What if there are commas at the start or end of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: you can define a character class (with "[]" inserting all chars you need, in this case \s (all sort of white spaces) and comma. Adding the "+" after the character class says that regexp must find one or more chars, so if you have " , " all chars will be replaced by one "|"

```js
console.log('809163294, 12345678 12345678 12345678'.replace(/[\s,]+/g,'|'))
```

P.s. fixed a misstyped a \W in place of a \s, sorry

Comment: `809163294,12345678 12345678, 12345678`

Comment: @JeremyThille: thanks for the suggestion! added a description of what the regexp do :)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `+` for more than one non word character and replace the group with a pipe.

```js
var string = '809163294, 12345678 12345678 12345678';

console.log(string.replace(/\W+/g, '|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following regex:

```js
var x = '809163294, 12345678 12345678 12345678'.replace(/[\s\,]+/g, '|');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This works, I would like to know why it has been silently downvoted.

Comment: I don't get it either. People just downvote everything within a few seconds if some tiny detail is missing or someone posted an answer 5 seconds earlier :/

Comment: I assume it's down voted (not me) because there's no explanation as to how it works, as @JeremyThille indicated ironically ;) (At least Roberto got'ya :)

Comment: Downvoters should never be silent. They're not being constructive and just leave an unpleasant feeling. The concerned person cannot learn from their mistakes. I've always said that SO should force downvoters to say _why_ they downvote, for educational purposes. (I always do)